# How to specify memory and internal storage allocation for android gradle managed devices

Tags: android, gradle, android-emulator, android-espresso, gradle-managed-device

When running android devices in parallel we can use something like:

```
./gradlew pixel4api30DebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.aaa.bbb.ccc.Suites.TestSuite -Pandroid.experimental.androidTest.numManagedDeviceShards=3
```

Typically when running tests via Android Studio we create the emulators and adjust the Memory and Internal Storage values in AVD Manager:
[image]

Is there a way to adjust these values via command line for the emulators that are spun up when running with gradle managed devices?